# Tensorflow : Export predictions to an array or a file

Tags: tensorflow, export-to-csv

As all the computations are made under a session, is there a way to export the predictions of Tensorflow to a Numpy/Pandas array or a file, i.e. CSV or TXT ?

Thanks !
Paul

Comment: You get results back in python land, so you should be able to use any python example.  I would probably just make a `results` object (Numpy/Pandas/list), and append results from `sess.run` to that, and write it out once you are done.

Comment: Concur with Jacob.  Jacob, would you copy your note to an answer so I can upvote it and give you credit? :) :)

Comment: Don't know why I hadn't thought of that... Thanks ! Paul

Answer (score 2):

You want to use something like...

```
im = Image.open('/home/kendall/Desktop/HA900_frames/frame0635.tif')
batch_x = np.array(im)
batch_x = batch_x.reshape((1, n_steps, n_input))
batch_x = batch_x.astype(float)
prediction = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: batch_x})
prediction = np.asarray(prediction)
prediction = np.reshape(prediction, (200,200))
np.savetxt("prediction.csv", prediction, delimiter=",")
```